# Serving two (ipython generated) reveal slide shows at once

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to be able to have two sets of slides, produced from two different notebooks, open at once in my browser. This use case is not supported, as far as I can tell, by the option `--post serve` of `ipython nbconvert --to slides` (of course, I'd be happy to be disproved).

My tactic has been to start a local server, as in

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001
```

and open the slide shows like this

```
google-chrome  http://127.0.0.1:8001/my.slides.html
```

but now I get a bunch of messages alike

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2015 12:03:49] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2015 12:03:49] "GET /reveal.js/css/reveal.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

whose meaning is quite clear to me... so I did

```
ln -s /path/to/local/copy/of/reveal.js/ .
google-chrome  http://127.0.0.1:8001/`
```

but now I have

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2015 12:07:29] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2015 12:07:29] "GET /custom.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

examining the source of `my.slides.html` I see the lines

```
<!-- Custom stylesheet, it must be in the same directory as the html file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
```

so I'm bound to the conclusion that `--post serve` does an awful lot of things at my back and that I'm out of luck in my attempt to save a standalone slide-show and have it served by a local HTTP server.

How can I have a properly served slide show without resorting to `--post serve`?

Comment: If you generate both of them in the same directoy, I think the server started by `--post serve` should be able to access them both. Alternatively, if you [download a copy of reveal.js](http://www.damian.oquanta.info/posts/using-a-local-revealjs-library-with-your-ipython-slides.html), then it will work with SimpleHTTPServer.